# PHP 7 strict_types seems to be turned on globally?

Tags: php, php-7.1

As per the title, in my WordPress 4.8, PHP 7.1 project, if I use type declarations in my methods, they are strict, not coercive. But nowhere have I declared to use strict types.

Does WordPress set this anywhere? I obviously did a search for the word `strict_types` but couldn't find anything.

Could it be enabled globally? Despite all the stuff I've read saying it can't be done?

To be more specific, my method signature is:

```
my_method(int $id, string $string)
```

And I'm calling it like:

```
my_method(123, null)
```

Comment: The server may have this installed: https://github.com/krakjoe/autostrict But other than that I have to question how you determine that `strict_types` is in effect.

Comment: Can you share with us the evidence that suggests to you that strict_types is on? Meaning code samples / messages your receive?

Comment: What types? Some types can't be coerced. (No offense intended, I'm not implying you don't know that. Just for clarity.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic it was a string that was causing the uncaught TypeError exception

Comment: Trying to be coerced to which type?

Comment: Oh sorry. My method was `function my_method( int $id, string $string )` and I was calling it with a `null` value for the `$string` e.g `my_method(123, null)` (which I was trying to catch to handle the error)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you asked this based on the example in your comment, some types can't be coerced to other types, even if [strict typing](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict) hasn't been enabled.

For example, with a meaningless implementation of the example method from your comment:

```
function my_method( int $id, string $string ) {
    var_dump($id, $string);
}
```

Passing a `null` value for the `$string` parameter *will* cause a [TypeError](http://php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php), even if things like

```
my_method(123, false);    // int 123, string ''
my_method(123, 456);      // int 123, string '456'
```

are able to be coerced to the indicated type without even a warning.

Since you're using PHP 7.1, you can use the new [nullable type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types) to allow null values.

```
function my_method( int $id, ?string $string) { ...
```